# Why is this React Components overlapping even it's set to position: static or relative 0

Tags: css, reactjs, overlapping

Just learning React!
I need help with why this menu overlaps like this image show:
The red ring, images go under the Menu and there's a horizontal scrollbars but there should not be one.

See [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-meadow-s5yrn?file=/src/Components/albumData.js)

[image]

This is the wrapper for the left Menu and the right MasonryGrid.

```
import React from 'react'
import '../Styles//Components/Wrapper-style.scss'
import Menu from './Menu'
const Wrapper = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="menu-container">
                <Menu />
            </div>
            <div className="children-container">
                {props.children}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default Wrapper
```

And this is the SCSS for the Wrapper

```
.wrapper{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  color: white;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.479);
  .menu-container{
 width: 100%; 
 height: 10%;
  }
  .children-container{
    position: relative;
    height: 85%;
    .content-container{
      &.page-enter {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      &.page-enter-active {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;
      }
      &.page-exit {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      &.page-exit-active {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 600ms ease-in-out;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
  }
}
@media(min-width:576px){
  .wrapper {
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 96vw;
    height: 96vh;
    border-radius: 5px;
    .menu-container {
      height: 100%;
      padding: 0;
      min-width: 20%;
      max-width: 20%;
    }
    .children-container {
      height: 100%;
      min-width: 80%;
      max-width: 80%;
    }
  }
}
```

Any ides why dies happened would be grate?

Comment: It's quite hard to tell without see and play with it. So if you can make a codesandbox which reproduce the issue, it will be much easier to debug.

Comment: Thanks Here's the [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-meadow-s5yrn?file=/src/Components/albumData.js) forked from [react-photographer-portfolio](https://github.com/emkozuch/react-photographer-portfolio). I only added the MasonryGrid and replaced images but MasonryGrid is to big

Comment: It's broken :( Can you fix it?

Comment: Give it time to load I think

Comment: `Could not find dependency: 'react-router-dom' relative to '/src/Components/Menu.js'` for example. Is it working for you as is?

Comment: I see that message to for 5 sec then app start as normal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219171/discussion-between-mosh-feu-and-erik).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the horizontal scrollbar, this will help.
Please add the marked line in AlbumPage-style.scss file.

```
.album.content-container .album-photos-container 
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow-x: hidden; <-------
}
```